# Set a program to run on windows startup from inside the program

Tags: java

I'm working on a  Java program and I would like to know how to set the program to run when windows is started from inside the program. Right now I have a config menu that has a checkbox with "run on windows startup", I need to create a class that, if the value saved in my config file equals 1, adds the .exe of the program to the "start at windows startup" list and if it equals 0 removes it. Searching on the internet yielded no decent results.

I thank you for the help! :)

Comment: I m not sure to understand what is bloking you ? the last time i did this, was by inserting a key in the registry..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will work, you could try to create a `.bat` file under `%appdata%\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\` with: `java -jar PATH_TO_JAR`